# Function signatures in export file (*.h) using bool return type

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have a file:

```
// mylib.c
// -------

#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_zero(int n)
{
  return (n == 0);
}
```

And a file detailing what functions to export:

```
// mylib.h
// -------

bool is_zero(int n);
```

When I compile, I get "mylib.o: error: unkown type name 'bool'"

Am I missing something? Do I need to do something special when my exported functions have a signature that requires an exported type?

Comment: Erm ... delete mylib.h, if you don't #include it then it is pointless.  That it actually gets included *somewhere* is the real problem you're trying to fix.  Deleting it will show you where :)  Put the #include for stdbool.h in that file, easy peasy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `stdbool.h` in `mylib.h` as well.

`bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool` type and this `bool` macro is defined in `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Well Proper way to do this is to move `#include <stdbool.h>` to mylib.h and then include mylib.h in mylib.c